# Unable to grant select privilege to role I've created

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g, roles

This is my statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE CATDX_OWNER.TBLAUTOSAVEDATA TO ROLE CATDX_OWNER_RPT_RL;
```

`CATDX_OWNER` is the schema name and the table name is `TBLAUTOSAVEDATA`, `CATDX_OWNER_RPT_RL` is the role I've created.

When running this, I get an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
>   00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

I've also swapped the schema name and table name with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Don't invent your own syntax. Remove both `TABLE` and `ROLE` from the `GRANT` statement.

```
GRANT SELECT ON CATDX_OWNER.TBLAUTOSAVEDATA TO CATDX_OWNER_RPT_RL;
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I'm very new to this as you may have noticed.

Comment: You're welcome. Documentation exists for reason; I suggest you to read it.